# I add you and I pay AND You can join if you want, but you pay

Tags: buttons, alerts, choices

In your opinion, how can I distinguish between two buttons that currently appear similar?

1. **Button A** allows me, as a user, to add a collaborator by paying $10.
2. **Button B** invites a collaborator who will have to pay the $10 themselves to activate the process.

In short, it would be necessary to distinguish between two concepts:

1. "I add you and I pay"
2. "You can join if you want, but you pay."

My typical user might risk adding too many collaborators at their own expense, causing problems. Therefore, I should be careful to avoid this issue by perhaps alerting them to the importance of the difference between the two buttons for their wallet.

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single button for adding a collaborator.

Then on the form where the data of the collaborator is entered, use a radio button to choose between:

- $10 fee paid by me when I click "Submit" below.
- $10 fee paid by collaborator when they decide to join.

The latter implies that the collaborator can decide not to join.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll want to split this into two workflows - adding collaborators, and making them into paid accounts.

A lot of services will allow a file owner to add collaborators for free. The collaborator accounts might have limited functionality (like a view-only statem or limited time access) until someone pays to upgrade them to full functionality.

The benefit of separating account creation from payment is that it'll give your users more control over managing the accounts later on. What happens if a paying collaborator doesn't want to pay anymore? The most graceful option is to keep the account active, but downgrade it to the limited level once more. This way, your file owner isn't stuck having to pay for a collaborator's account just to keep them from disappearing from the system.

And if the collaborator needs to work on other files that don't belong to the original file owner, it'll be easier to sort that out if the payment is separated.